# Additional data storage drives in UEFI

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

My motherboard (MSI A68HM-E33 V2) has the UEFI BIOS. I want to put in three extra drives for storage and to recover information already on these drives. UEFI recognizes my boot and one additional drive. These are hard drives that were in other computer systems. I want to view their content and recover some files.

How can I get the additional hard drives to be seen?

I need to see the contents and get some files off these additional drives.

My motherboard is configured for Legacy and UEFI. I do not want to boot off of these other drives.

Comment: Have you tried just connecting the drives? If you're concerned about which drive may be booted from, use the manual boot selection mode in your BIOS, or adjust your BIOS settings, to boot from your OS drive. But it sounds like you haven't tried anything yet. Please try things and let us know what you learn and if you still have a question after.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect your drives as external ones in a docking station. Provided that your booting operating systems understands the file systems used on those additional drives you will be able to read them out.

You might also connect them as internal ones. Upon restart you would need to open your UEFI-Bios settings to prevent booting from them.